# Points don't show up on an overlaying shapefile?

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, r

```
library(ggmap)
library(rgdal)

cities<-c("city A","city B")
country<-readOGR(dsn=".",layer="country")
gc<-geocode(cities,source="google")
gc$names<-c("city A","city B")
coordinates(gc)<-~lon+lat
proj4string(gc)<-proj4string(country) #because the "gc" doesnt have a crs at the moment
gc<-spTransform(gc,CRS(proj4string(country)))
plot(country)
plot(gc,add=T)
```

Result is that the points are not in the map at all. What is wrong? CRS, projection is the same, so it should have been working.

The point of this endeavor is to make the "cities" to appear in the shapefile of the country. Something in the projection has to be wrong although they appear to be the same.

The reason i put  `proj4string(gc)<-proj4string(country)` before the `spTransform` line is because you can't use the `spTransform` function on something that has NA values for projection.

Comment: Please use words to introduce code.  A description of the environment, and what you are attempting to accomplish are critical to determine whether you are proceeding correctly.

Comment: You are assigning an __assumed__ CRS to 'gc' - then spTransform-ing it to the same CRS, which does nothing. You need to investigate the coordinates of gc (`bbox(gc)` or `summary()`) and see what you get - perhaps edit and paste the results of `summary()` in the question here?

Comment: Doing, proj4string(gc) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84") to the empty gc before the spTransform, made it appear in the right place.Do you know why it worked?

Comment: It will work - or seem to work - if the CRS of the 'empty' gc is the same or similar to 4326 (WGS84 latlon). Might **appear to** work (but not be accurate) if it's another unprojected CRS, like Arc 1960.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is not reproducible and you do not use `library( )` statements to show which packages you are using. This makes it difficult to help you.

You state that "CRS, projection is the same" but you provide no evidence for that. What I do know is that these lines make no sense:

```
proj4string(gc) <- proj4string(country)
gc <- spTransform(gc, CRS(proj4string(country)))
```

You first declare the coordinates of `gc` to have the same CRS as `country`. In the next step you transform the coordinates to the CRS that they already have, which is pointless. Perhaps check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166876/alternatives-of-sptransform) discussion.

I assume that `geocode` returns lon/lat values. If so, you probably should do

```
proj4string(gc) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
gc <- spTransform(gc, CRS(proj4string(country)))
```

Comment: Just for others' sake, `geocode` is from `ggmap`

Comment: It also exists in `dismo` and who knows where else.

Comment: no, this is `ggmap`. `source="google"` kinda gives it away.